# Restricting search to a subset of document fields

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

Is it possible to restrict the GAE full text search to specific document fields? In other words, if the query is only matched to contents of the field being ignored, could that document be excluded from search results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict a search term to a specific field, but there's no convenient way to exclude, say, just one or two fields if there are many fields in the documents.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/#Queries_on_Fields

Comment: Bingo! I looked only at the Java Search API and the query text API slipped my mind - thank you.